# Find and delete an item from a collection

Tags: jpa, collections

I have the following problem with a method of JPA.
I can not delete an item from a collection.
Actually, the method only works if it is not the last element inserted.
Where I'm wrong?

This is the class of my model:

```
@Entity
public class JobOffer {

  @SequenceGenerator(name="JobOffer_Gen", sequenceName="JobOffer_Seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
  @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="JobOffer_Gen") @Column(name="ID_JOBOFFER")
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String title;

    ...

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "JOBOFFER_IDFK"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_IDFK"))
  private Collection<Language> languages = new HashSet<Language>();

    ...
}
```

This is my method in JPA:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteLanguage(JobOffer joboffer, Long idLingua) throws BusinessException {
    for(Language l : joboffer.getLanguages()){
        if (l.getId() == idLingua){ 
            joboffer.getLanguages().remove(l);

        }
    }
    em.merge(joboffer);
}
```

What is the correct way to search for an item in a collection and delete in JPA?

This is the error that I get from the console:

```
21-ott-2013 18.22.27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jobbook] in context with path [/jobbook] threw     exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is       java.util.ConcurrentModificationException] with root cause
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList$1.next(IndirectList.java:571)
at it.univaq.mwt.j2ee.jobbook.business.impl.JPAJobOfferService.deleteLanguage(JPAJobOfferService.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

and then continues

Comment: Add an extract of your error trace please.

Comment: if you iterate over a collection (using an iterator like you do implicit via for(Language l : joboffer.getLanguages()) ), you mustn't modify the collection (what you do via joboffer.getLanguages().remove(l); )

Comment: mmmmmm... ok...I understand. 
How can I delete an item from a collection in jpa?
How can I make entityManager.find in JobOffer.getLanguages ​​()

Comment: Use an Iterator and call iter.remove

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.
But my question was also to know if it is correct to act in this way or if there is a way to search an object in a collection with FIND of the Entity Manager

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteLanguage(JobOffer joboffer, Long idLingua) throws BusinessException {
  Language language = em.createQuery("SELECT lang from Language lang where lang.jobOffer.id = :job_id", Language.class).setParameter("job_id", joboffer.getId()).getSingleResult();
  if(language != null){
    joboffer.getLanguages().remove(language);
  }
}
```

Please note:

- this is not tested
- I assumed that your "Language" Entity has a reference to your JobOffer Entity. Although I do not know your domain, this **may** indicate a bad design
- If the parameter joboffer is in detached state, then you have to reattach it to the current session (using em.merge()).

---

Edit: Adapted Query in response to the comment of DataNucleus.

Comment: with "SELECT lang " as a prefix to that illegal JPQL query of course.

Comment: Language entity does not have a reference to JobOffer. :-(
Languages ​​are indipendendi.

Comment: @DataNucleus: Just tried a mini example and this works as expected: em.createQuery("from Pojo p where p.myNumber = :job_id",    Pojo.class).setParameter("job_id", 1).getSingleResult();
So no need for SELECT lang, or do I miss something important?

user1826663: Then it's okay, I did not look at your mapping carefully enough ;)

Comment: Yes, you miss something - reading the JPA spec. What Hibernate docs portray as valid JPQL is not (it is "HQL" and that is vendor specific ... so you limit your application to where it can be used ... which beats the point of using a standard), and the user doesn't say anywhere they are using Hibernate

Comment: I didn't know that --> +1 for pointing this out. 
According to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html you're right ;)